# React: Unexpected token return

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and I have this following code:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" name="texte" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <input type="submit" value="Valider" onClick={this.update} />
                </form>
                var list = this.state.liste.map(function(elt) {
                    return <li>{elt}</li>
                });
                <ul>{list}</ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

I have a syntax error:

```
Unexpected token return <li>{elt}</li>
                 ^
```

I don't understand why...
Thanks for any help!

Comment: If the answer helped you please make sure to accept it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restructure your code like this:

```
render() {

var list = this.state.liste.map(function(elt) {
                    return <li>{elt}</li>
                });
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" name="texte" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <input type="submit" value="Valider" onClick={this.update} />
                </form>

                <ul>{list}</ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

or

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" name="texte" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <input type="submit" value="Valider" onClick={this.update} />
                </form>
                <ul>{this.state.liste.map(function(elt) {
                    return <li>{elt}</li>
                });}</ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

You can't add code inside the JSX syntax without `{}`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Comment: You can only put code as expressions inside the brackets.